# maven clean install does not generate an artifact SNAPSHOT.jar

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm making my first steps in Spring Boot and embedded servers. I found this [In28Minutes Tutorial](http://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-with-embedded-servers-tomcat-jetty) which is pretty easy to follow. Now I stuck trying to generate an artifact SNAPSHOT.jar file, which I would import into my RCP-project. Running `maven clean install` didn't help. Can anyone help me out? Hier are the some informations:

1. Spring Boot framework
2. Spring Boot Starts use Tomcat by default as an embedded server container

Hier is the console output

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building demo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ demo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ demo ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ demo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/borisnguema/Documents/test-workspace/demo/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ demo ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) @ demo ---
[INFO]
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Console output (End)

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   DemoApplicationTests.initializationError » IllegalState Unable to find a @Spri...
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.296 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-10T14:41:23+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/437M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) on project demo: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /Users/borisnguema/Documents/test-workspace/demo/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Main:

```
package bookmarks;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import bookmarks.entity.Account;
import bookmarks.entity.Bookmark;
import bookmarks.repository.IAccountRepository;
import bookmarks.repository.IBookmarkRepository;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner init(IAccountRepository accountRepository, IBookmarkRepository bookmarkRepository) {
        return (evt) -> Arrays.asList("jhoeller,dsyer,pwebb,ogierke,rwinch,mfisher,mpollack,jlong".split(","))
                .forEach(a -> {
                    Account account = accountRepository.save(new Account(a, "password"));
                    bookmarkRepository.save(new Bookmark(account, "http://bookmark.com/1/" + a, "A description"));
                    bookmarkRepository.save(new Bookmark(account, "http://bookmark.com/2/" + a, "A description"));
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is certainly not the whole log. Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: Try `clean package`, on success, a jar will be created inside targets folder

Comment: Please share your pom.xml

Comment: I just edited with the pom.xml

Comment: @PriyeshKumar `install` implies `package`.

Comment: @Lycone, note that if you're using Eclipse, it's much better to "Import -> Existng Maven projects" instead of using a bare jar file.

Comment: @chrylis that i can try... Didn't really think about it. I'll try and get back to you. Even though I don't really know how to do it, since I have a RCP-project.

Comment: just checked your pom file - copy-paste - and it works fine. In your question you wrote "maven clean install" - is it a missprint and you meant "mvn clean install"? or you did an error? And I agree with @YassinHajaj, looks like your log is not full.

Comment: And did you create @SpringBootApplication?

Answer (score 0):

So I will try to assume, that you didn't create main class and somewhere down you should have something like that:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.410 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-10T18:26:06+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 32M/1266M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.2.RELEASE:repackage (default) on project demo: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.2.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to find main class -> [Help 1]
```

For makeing this working add main class to your src/main/java folder

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

In result of execution of `mvn clean install` at the end of log you should have:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.043 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-10T18:29:38+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 40M/1004M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And in target you will get your `demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Hope this will help.

Comment: I updated my post... As you can see, I've got a main. But you right I've got "BUILD FAILURE". I thought, it was because a test failed so I didn't bother.

Answer (score 0):

I owe you guys an apology. I messed up big. I was having two test packages as you can see on the picture below. So the first is rightfully set up, but the second wasn't. That is the reason why I had one test failure I couldn't explain. Now, I removed the package and Maven runs trough. Nevertheless, I want to thank you guys for trying to help me with a problem that wasn't really one in the first place :-)

[image]